# Multiple Content Filters Gravity View Plugin For Gravity Forms Plugin For WordPress

Tags: wordpress, forms

We are working with filters using the Gravity View plugin for Gravity Forms for WordPress. Not super good at filters yet, so hoping to get a little help with this if possible. We have a filter when added, that filters out certain content, based on the Gravity Form field ID. In the example below, we are filtering out the Gravity Form field with an ID of 18.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'gravityview/fields/custom/content_before', 'my_gv_custom_content_before', 10, 1 );
function my_gv_custom_content_before( $content ) {
$id = '18';
global $gravityview_view;
extract( $gravityview_view->field_data );
if( empty( $entry[ (string)$id ] ) ) {
return '';
}
return $content;
}
```

This works. Then taking it a step further, we are told we can add something to this filter to filter out multiple Gravity Form field ids using this something like this added to our example above. In this example, filtering Field 18 & 26:

```
if( ( false !== strpos( $content, '{MY_FIELD_NAME:18}') && empty( $entry['18'] ) ) || ( ( false !== strpos( $content, '{MY_FIELD_NAME:26}') && empty( $entry['26'] )  ) ) {
return '';
}
```

What would the two look like combined? For example, if we wanted to filter field id 18, 26 and perhaps a third field 34? Using the first part of the code example and then the second example, what would they look like combined? Could anyone provide an example?

Have been playing with this and not having much luck combining it all into one filter. Keep getting errors and I am sure we don't have something quite right. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked out, here is the code in case anyone needs it.

```
/** Modify the content returned from the Custom Content field */
add_filter( 'gravityview/fields/custom/content_before', 'my_gv_custom_content_before', 10, 1 );
/**
* Removes the custom content field's content in case a certain entry field is empty
*
* @param string $content Custom Content field content
* @return string
*/
function my_gv_custom_content_before( $content ) {
global $gravityview_view;
extract( $gravityview_view->field_data );
// field_id => merge_tag
$validation = array(
'18' => '{Custom Background:18}',
'26' => '{New YouTube Video Test:26}',
'28' => '{New Vimeo:28}'
);
foreach( $validation as $id => $merge ) {
if( false !== strpos( $content, $merge ) && empty( $entry[ (string)$id ] ) ) {
return '';
}
}
return $content;
}
```